# How to differentiate between Mulitple alarms in android

Tags: android

In the Android app which is getting developed, i have multiple alarms.

I want to initiate, different actions on different alarms.

How can i differentiate or determine , exactly which alarm has been fired??

Rgds
Yaaga

Answer (score 3):

When you set your alarms with AlarmManager you give each of them a PendingIntent which must be bound to an Intent. You can use that Intents' extras bundle to distinguish between different alarms (by putting in an int or a String, say).